# Cast without unsafe between struct and Span<byte> and vice versa in .C# and NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, ref, .net-5

I try to **cast** a struct to a Span and back (so that the original struct can be changed). That worked partially. How can I cast the Span back into a struct (don't copy) ?

Here is my try. Unfortunately it doesn't work when casting back:

```
internal struct TestStruct
{
    internal byte ByteValue;
    internal ushort UshortValue;
    internal uint UintValue;
    internal ulong UlongValue;

    internal TestStruct(byte byteValue,ushort ushortValue, uint uintValue, ulong ulongValue) {
        ByteValue = byteValue;
        UshortValue = ushortValue;
        UintValue = uintValue;
        UlongValue = ulongValue;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TestStruct structInstance = new TestStruct( 0xAA, 0xAAAA, 0xAAAAAAAA, 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA );            
        var span1 = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<TestStruct>(ref structInstance, 1);
        span1[0].ByteValue = 0x11;
        Debug.WriteLine($"span1[0].ByteValue = 0x11 => 0x{structInstance.ByteValue:X2}");
        var byteSpan1 = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes<TestStruct>(span1);
        byteSpan1[0] = 0x22;
        Debug.WriteLine($"byteSpan1[0] = 0x22 => 0x{structInstance.ByteValue:X2}");
        TestStruct structAgain = MemoryMarshal.AsRef<TestStruct>(byteSpan1);
        structAgain.ByteValue = 0xBB;
        Debug.WriteLine($"structAgain.ByteValue = 0xBB => 0x{structInstance.ByteValue:X2}");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
span1[0].ByteValue = 0x11 => 0x11
byteSpan1[0] = 0x22 => 0x22
structAgain.ByteValue = 0xBB => 0x22
```

Obviously MemoryMarshal.AsRef  () gives a copy and does not cast. Is there a way to get it working?

Comment: Is there any compelling reason to avoid `unsafe`?

Comment: No, obviously `MemoryMarshal.AsRef` does *not* give a copy but obviously copying the value of what it returns into a separate value type variable does. Try `ref TestStruct structAgain = ref MemoryMarshal.AsRef<TestStruct>(byteSpan1);` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that `struct` is a value type. This means, each struct field/parameter/local variable contains the entire value of the struct. Your `TestStruct structAgain` is an independent copy of your original `structInstance`. Changes to the copy do not affect the original, and vice versa.

What you want is a reference to your original struct. To do this, you need the `ref` keyword. If you look at [MemoryMarshal.AsRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.asref), you see the return type is `ref T`. This means it is returning a reference. You can save the reference by declaring your local variable as `ref TestStruct structAgain = ref MemoryMarshal.AsRef<TestStruct>(byteSpan1);`. Now structAgain is no longer a copy, but a reference to the original.

Comment: His was an error, not something he did voluntarily. There is no warning if you make the `ref` returned by `MemoryMarshal.AsRef` "precipitate" to a value type (and in doing so creating a copy) by removing the `ref` keyword. Your solution still is correct.